# Use non-system font in invoice environment

Tags: fonts, invoice

I want to use a non-system font with the `invoice` environment nested in the `scrlttr2` document class. Normally to specify the font I want within a normal letter with `scrlttr2` (without the `invoice` package) this works fine:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Normal-GroteskNormal.otf}
```

However, the values in the Amount column in the invoice block within the scrlttr2 are the default LaTeX serif font. How do I apply Normal-GroteskNormal.otf there too?

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{invoice}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Normal-GroteskNormal.otf}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\Large}

\begin{document}
    \setkomavar{fromname}{Josefina Jones}
    \setkomavar{fromaddress}{My address}
    
    \setkomavar{date}{\today}
    \setkomavar{place}{Here}

    \begin{letter} {%
        Addressee\\
        Address
    }

        \opening{Invoice \#123}
        
        \begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
            \ProjectTitle{Test}
            \Fee{Stuff} {5000} {1}
            \EBC{Expense} {200}
        \end{invoice}

        \closing{Ciao,}
        
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[This issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657357/changing-the-font-of-an-environment/663795#663795) seemed useful but I don't use a custom stylesheet and the poster was using an alternative system font.

Answer (score 2):

The `scrlttr2` class has nothing to do with the issue.

The “amount” column uses math mode, in order to accommodate the minus sign.

You need to change how digits are typeset in math mode, which is not so hard.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Futura}[
  NFSSFamily=myfont,
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{amount}{TU}{myfont}{m}{n}
\Umathcode`0="7 \symamount `0
\Umathcode`1="7 \symamount `1
\Umathcode`2="7 \symamount `2
\Umathcode`3="7 \symamount `3
\Umathcode`4="7 \symamount `4
\Umathcode`5="7 \symamount `5
\Umathcode`6="7 \symamount `6
\Umathcode`7="7 \symamount `7
\Umathcode`8="7 \symamount `8
\Umathcode`9="7 \symamount `9
\Umathcode`-="2 \symamount "2212

\begin{document}

\begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
  \ProjectTitle{Test}
  \Fee{Stuff} {5000} {1}
  \EBC{Expense} {200}
\end{invoice}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since I don't have your font, I used another very distinctive one. If that font has no minus sign U+2212 character, you can probably substitute with a similar minus sign

```
\newfontface{\minussign}{FONTWITHMINUSSIGN}[
  NFSSFamily=minussign,
]
\DeclareSymbolFont{minussign}{TU}{minussign}{m}{n}
\Umathcode`-= "2 \symminussign "2212
```

Comment: Success! Many thanks @egreg.